# RADIUS server on VPN set up

Tags: vpn, radius, rras, nps

Just a quick question, hoping for a quick answer.  I'm studying for my MCSA and I'm a little confused about RADIUS.  Currently I have a VPN server set up with RRAS and NPS on my home server lab.  Does that make the VPN Server a RADIUS server if it's the one currently processing Connection and Network requests?  Or is the DC a RADIUS server as the NPS uses Active Directory on the DC to authenticate requests?  Or RADIUS a-whole-nother concept of authentication?

The Domain Controller has AD, DHCP and DNS installed on it.  The VPN server only has RRAS and NPS installed.

The books I'm reading aren't very clear on that, or I'm just not reading it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RRAS is the Radius client, NPS is the Radius server.
You have installed both of these services on the same node, so this node hosts the Radius client and server parts. The DC has nothing to do with Radius.

Comment: Thank you.  That does pretty much explain it best for me.  I forgot about RRAS being a client.